# CSS Label layout affecting Slider

Tags: html, css, slider

I'm using CSS to space out form fields and there text labels.
This works fine, but I also want to use a CSS CheckBox slider, which is configured using a LABEL.

The combination of `label` CSS for the form field labels and the slider are messing up the slider layout.

I've created a **[JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/53k558z9/2/)** showing the form field layout, how this is affecting the slider and a working slider when the extra CSS is not involved.

Working Slider:

```
 <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' value="1" />
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </label>
```

failing slider:

```
<div class='spaced'>
  <label>Form Label</label>
  <a href='#' title=""><img src="help.png"></a>

  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' value="1" />
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction how to have a working slider spaced as the other fields.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style definitions of the "div.spaced label" selector are overriding the styles of the ".switch" selector.

I suggest you to create a seperated div inside the label element:

```
<label>
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' value="1" />
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
</label>
```

This will fix the width problem. To positionate the "a-tag" on the left side of the slider it also needs the float (left) property:

```
div.spaced a {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; // Optional margin
}
```

Hint: You can use **flexbox** as a better layout system :)

I hope i could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I'm not sure how to apply what your suggesting. Could you update my fiddle ? Thanks